# MACHINE=foo is invalid. Please set a valid MACHINE in your local.conf

Tags: yocto, bitbake

When starting my build, I get:

```
ERROR:  OE-core's config sanity checker detected a potential misconfiguration.
    Either fix the cause of this error or at your own risk disable the checker (see sanity.conf).
    Following is the list of potential problems / advisories:

    MACHINE=foo is invalid. Please set a valid MACHINE in your local.conf, environment or other configuration file.
```

Inside `build/conf/local.conf` file, I tell bitbake to build that machine:

```
MACHINE = 'foo'
```

Online search did not return useful results for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the machine name `foo` in your local.conf is correct.

Also make sure that there is a valid configuration for that machine in some meta layer.
I.e. search for a `conf/machine/foo.conf` file in all meta-foobar directories.

```bash
find . -wholename "*conf/machine*" | grep foo  # Remove grep to see all MACHINEs
```